# Jerk while scrolling when tableView inside tableview Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableofcontents, contentsize

I am using `UITableview` inside `tableView` for one of my screen. Here I have one, `InstalmentMainTableViewCell` and `InstalmentInnerTableViewCell`.

I used below code to scroll inner `tableView` with full height:

```
class InnerTableView: UITableView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        //This is for extra space after inner tableview size. can be required
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
        return self.contentSize
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is when I am scrolling from to second cell of `MainTableViewCell` from first it is getting stuck for a second and never happens again. It is only happening for first time whenever the view-controller appears.

Here is the full code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch (tableView.tag) {
    case 100:
        return instalmentModel.count == 0 ? 0 : instalmentModel.count
    default:
        return instalmentModel[currentInstalmentIndex].EMIDetailModel.count == 0 ? 0 : instalmentModel[currentInstalmentIndex].EMIDetailModel.count
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch (tableView.tag) {
    case 100:

        currentInstalmentIndex = indexPath.row

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: InstalmentsMainTableViewCell.className) as! InstalmentsMainTableViewCell

        if let model = self.instalmentModel[indexPath.row] as InstalmentModel? {

            if tableView.visibleCells.contains(cell) {
                self.putValue(self.yearLabel, "\(String(describing: model.year!))")
            }
            cell.emiTotal,text = "\(model.year!)"
        }
        return cell

    default:

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: InstalmentsInnerTableViewCell.className) as! InstalmentsInnerTableViewCell

        if let model = self.instalmentModel[self.currentInstalmentIndex].EMIDetailModel[indexPath.row] as EMIDetailModel? {

            cell.indicatorView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        }
        return cell
    }
}

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    let indexPath = self.instalmentsTableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows?[0]
    if let model = instalmentModel[(indexPath?.row)!] as InstalmentModel? {
        putValue(yearLabel, "\(model.year!)")
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
}
```

The requirement is:
[Requirement for tableView inside tableview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIzLF.png)

Comment: When the inner table has the same height as it's its content height it means it will always display all the cells with no reusing. That's memory intense and you won't ever achieve good performance that way. Solution: don't use table views nested in other scroll views. Use one table view with sections instead.

Comment: But, that is making code so complex for my requirement. I have attached the required design this whole page is repeating along with the bottom view which leads me to have two tables. Can you please have a look ?

Comment: Just use sections. The last section can have different cells. The bottom view can actually be just a single cell if necessary.

Comment: Ok. I will try.

Comment: Also, calling `layoutIfNeeded ` inside `intrinsicContentSize` is probably the thing that makes your table view so slow. It would be better to use key-value observing on `contentSize` and then call `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()`.

Comment: Ok. Basically, the tableview is not slow, I am receiving good performance. It is just stucking when I am scrolling from first cell to second of outer tableview.

Comment: I have tried adding observer but it is still getting stuck on the same point. Can you please give a brief idea how can I use section in this case. Any reference .. !

Comment: Hi @Sulthan Thanks for section suggestion. It helped. :)